# How to get id based on username and password using Web API and Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, model-view-controller, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

I need to get only from table based on username and password.

I am using Xamarin cross-platform, and Web API to connect to SQL Server.

Here is my code:

**Web Api - Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("XAMARIN_Login")]      
public IHttpActionResult GetId(string username, string password)
{
    var result = db.AspNetUsers
        .Where(x => x.UserName == username && x.PasswordHash == password)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

**Xamarin - RestClient.cs**

```
private const string WebloginUrl = "http://172.16.4.212:55364/api/AspNetUsers/GetId/";

public async Task<List<T>> checkLogin(string username, string password)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(
        WebloginUrl + "?username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);

    var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
    return taskModels;
}
```

**Xamarin - Services.cs**

```
public async Task<List<UserDetail>> GetId(string username, string password)
{
    RestClient<UserDetail> userDetail = new RestClient<UserDetail>();
    var user = await userDetail.checkLogin(username, password);
    return user;
}
```

**Xamarin - MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Employee"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Employee.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Employee.MainPage" Title="Kulsum International Hospital">
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="EntryUsername" />
        <Entry x:Name="EntryPassword" />
        <Entry x:Name="Id" /> 

        <!-- what I want when user click on button Id should appear in this entry -->
        <Button x:Name="ButtonLogin" Clicked="ButtonLogin_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Xamarin - MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void ButtonLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployeesServices services = new EmployeesServices();
    var getLoginDetails = await services.GetId(EntryUsername.Text, EntryPassword.Text);
    // Here I don't know what to do to get id in entry
}
```

I have uploaded all my code now. This code working absolutely fine, but I am just confused on the last step. I don't know how to show the id in entry when a user clicks on the button.

Comment: Do you want to set id Entry based on Id you get from the service?

Comment: i have 3 entries, as you can see in my code when i put username and password and click on button, i want to display id on 3rd entry based on username and password

Comment: Did you try this? 
`Id.Text = getLoginDetails.Id`

Comment: it will not work like this

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting ID property value in `getLoginDetails`? Why can't you assign the ID property value to label text?

Comment: GetID returns a List<UserDetail>, so you (presumably) need to do getLoginDetails[0].Id

Comment: @Jason  i have tried with your code still not working can you please check is my code ok..? or i did something wrong in code

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description.  Does it crash?  Give an error?  Have you used the debugger to step through your code and verify its behavior?

Comment: i am getting null value in my id text and i am getting this error `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "a0356d19-0ee3-4570-8499-8da6e4b1be7c" to type 'Employee.Models.UserDetail'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 39`

Comment: by the way this is actual id - a0356d19-0ee3-4570-8499-8da6e4b1be7c

Comment: here is my code `private async void ButtonLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmployeesServices services = new EmployeesServices();
           var getLoginDetails = await services.GetUserDetailAsync(EntryUsername.Text, EntryPassword.Text);
            Id.Text = getLoginDetails[0].Id;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

use token based authentication, you can have a look here https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UToBKlnig4M

Comment: Could you summarize or provide a code sample or more information?

Comment: Works great, in a video by Houssem Dellai he explains that if you have a user who connected to your website via web api, on the web side you need to make sure the user exists and he connected to the system. And you do it with one line of code in any action or controller:- var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId ();